# How can I active a wordpress plugin after upload from back-end source code

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm facing a problem which is wordpress plugin related. I've deactived WooCommerce plugin for a reason from wp dashboard then my site is not showing any kinds of WooCommerce related topic. And after that I can't access my wp-admin panel **"Error thrown
Call to undefined function WC()"** this message is showing. I think if I can active the plugin again then the problem will be solved. But I still can't access admin panel. So, I want to active it again from site cPanel back-end source code. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

-Arefin

Comment: activate the plugin from your DB

Comment: I can't access Dashboard. And that's the problem!

Comment: You could access Cpanel. From there you should be able to access DB using phpMyAdmin

Comment: I already tried this method, no effort! :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it from database.
First go to PHPMyadmin & select your database and go to the **wp_options** table. In options table find `active_plugins` in `option_name` field.

Here you will find like below(Format done for understanding)

```
a:5:{
  i:0;s:33:"classic-editor/classic-editor.php";
  i:1;s:36:"contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php";
  i:2;s:31:"custom-plugin/custom-plugin.php";
  i:3;s:47:"jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/jwt-auth.php";
  i:5;s:29:"wp-mail-smtp/wp_mail_smtp.php";
}
```

Now add your woocommerce plugin into this. For adding plugin increment `a to 6(a:6) from 5(a:5)` and add your plugin. In this array `i` stands for item number & `s` stands for string length

```
a:6:{
  i:0;s:33:"classic-editor/classic-editor.php";
  i:1;s:36:"contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php";
  i:2;s:31:"custom-plugin/custom-plugin.php";
  i:3;s:47:"jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/jwt-auth.php";
  i:4;s:27:"woocommerce/woocommerce.php";
  i:5;s:29:"wp-mail-smtp/wp_mail_smtp.php";
}
```